# How to force bashls, shellcheck to treat zsh files as bash using lspconfig?

Tags: neovim, lsp

Most of my dotfile scripts are in `zsh`, with the `.zsh` extension and shebang - `#!/usr/bin/env zsh`.

Formatting and linting does not work in zsh files out of the box (understandably so); however, they can still be very useful for these files.

**I would like to treat them as if they were bash files for formatting/linting purposes.**

When changing the shebang to use `bash` instead, it all works. But I would like to keep the shebang as-is.

- I tried changing the config but I am not sure which settings to change. [The documentation for lspconfig bashls](https://github.com/neovim/nvim-lspconfig/blob/master/doc/server_configurations.md#bashls) doesn't
  show all the available values for override so I'm not sure what to
  update.

  ```
  lspconfig.bashls.setup({
    filetypes = { "sh", "zsh" }
  })
  ```
- I also tried exporting `SHELLCHECK_OPTS='--shell=bash'` to force it on the user level but it doesn't seem like shellcheck is reading this when being run in vim, although [the docs](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/blob/master/shellcheck.1.md#environment-variables) specify something like this should work.

In fact, I'm not sure what exactly I should update - I know both shellcheck and bashls are installed via Mason. I am not sure how to configure them and which needs the attention.

Is it maybe actually neovim that does the detection, so I should add an `ftdetect` entry to handle this?

Can anyone shed some light and point me in the right direction?

Comment: I'd guess you need to specify `allowlist` like mentioned here: https://github.com/bash-lsp/bash-language-server/blob/main/README.md?plain=1#L68-L75

Comment: Does it work the way you like if you use `:let g:is_bash = 1` and then after opening one of the zsh files you use `:set filetype=sh`? I guess one way to getting bash-like features on your zsh files is treating them as _actual_ bash. If that works, then we can find a way to configure that as a more permanent configuration, to do so automatically every time you open them. What do you think?

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't seem like changing either of these works :( as for the allowlist, I am not sure where to put it for lspconfig, but I tried a few options - putting it in `setup({ settings = { ... }})` and putting it in `setup({ ... })` directly... neither worked. Thanks for the effort :) would love more ideas

Comment: bash and zsh have different semantics, so I'm not sure if what you want is even a good idea in the first place to be honest. Compare `x=*; echo $x` in bash and zsh for example. Arrays work different, builtins are different, and many other things. shellcheck doesn't even parse my `~/.zshrc`, and after I fixed a few "syntax errors" I got many spurious warnings that don't apply to zsh. It's your editor, but I think it will be very confusing.

Comment: Related issues: https://github.com/bash-lsp/bash-language-server/issues/252 and https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/issues/809 – [zsh-sweep](https://github.com/psprint/zsh-sweep) was mentioned as an alternative (I didn't read the entire thread so there may be others). I didn't try it, so I can't tell you if it's any good.